# Change set migration to production

Tags: migration

probably really easy question here. What is the recommended way to simply migrate change sets (custom fields, apex code) from sandbox to production?

Should this be done to a newly created Org then make everyone a part of the org? Any experience here would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you setup a Sandbox for your org, you have a few different options (Developer, Developer Pro, Partial Copy, Full Copy), and you decide whether data in a ChangeSet can flow...

> 1. Sandbox > Production (One way, ChangeSets from SBX to Prod)
> 2. Production > Sandbox (One way, ChangeSets from Prod to SBX)
> 3. Sandbox <--> Production (2 Way, ChangeSets can be deployed from Sandbox to Production or from Production to Sandbox)

Generally, customers with large organizations or lots of customization will have a 'middle tier' sandbox, sometimes referred to as a UAT (User Acceptance Testing) environment, which is used for bulk DML testing, user testing of new features, integrations testing and debug. **If your org has a lot of custom apex, process builders, or integrations with other applications then you'd likely want either a FULL Copy or Partial Copy Sandbox in-between your Dev Sandbox and your Production environment**

---

### **So, in this case, your Sandbox setup might look like this:**

Dev Sandbox > UAT Sandbox > Production

In the case of my org, we have our Dev sandbox setup so that it can send ChangeSets to UAT or directly to Production - we do this so that we don't need to rebuild the ChangeSet again in UAT to send to Production, but we ALWAYS send to UAT first, test appropriately, and then only send to Production after tests in UAT are confirmed successful. By doing it this way, if the ChangeSet worked perfectly in UAT you can just push the same ChangeSet from Dev straight to Production and Validate/Deploy.

Some items and configurations cannot be pushed via ChangeSets, one of the most important ones is Standard Fields. **You CANNOT send Standard Fields in a ChangeSet, so any changes you make to these fields (labels, new picklist values, dependencies, etc) need to be re-created manually in each environment**

Additionally, its considered a good practice to always include all of your User Profiles in a ChangeSet when pushing to a new environment. Profiles are a sort of 'selective' include, and by including them you are ONLY including the permissions related to the other objects/fields in the ChangeSet. For example: If you create 3 new fields in Sandbox and only 2 profiles have access to them, you want to copy your profiles in the SAME ChangeSet that the fields are in, to make sure that your profile settings for those new fields are carried over. Profiles ARE NOT overwritten in full when you copy profiles, it only takes into account permissions related to objects in the current ChangeSet. If you forget to copy profiles and you deploy the ChangeSet, you'll need to manually adjust profiles/field level security in the receiving org.

For additional information, check out the Salesforce Help on ChangeSets, in the See Also section at the bottom you'll see related information regarding Deployment Connections (which orgs can send data to which orgs), Outbound vs Inbound sets, components available in a Change Set, and special behaviors:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets.htm